# How do I tag myself in Google photos?

Tags: google-photos

Google photos identified me in some of the old photos. In newer photos it identifies me as someone else. I tried to change it, but I am not able to tag with term *me*.
Finally I created my own contact and tagged it with my name. However I am not able to search those photos with term *me*.

I want to tag my face with *me*, how do I?